# In Vue3 composition API make the watcher work immediately

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Using Vue3 composition API. How do I make watched to work immediately. The following code doesn't work.

```
watch((immediate=true) => props.isOpen, () => {
        if (props.isOpen && props.preventBackgroundScrolling) {
          document.body.style.setProperty('overflow', 'hidden')
        } else {
          document.body.style.removeProperty('overflow')
        }

          });
```

Comment: keyword arguments aren't even valid JavaScript

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It should placed as option :

```
watch(() => props.isOpen, () => {
        if (props.isOpen && props.preventBackgroundScrolling) {
          document.body.style.setProperty('overflow', 'hidden')
        } else {
          document.body.style.removeProperty('overflow')
        }

          },{immediate:true});
```

or

```
watch('props.isOpen', () => {
        if (props.isOpen && props.preventBackgroundScrolling) {
          document.body.style.setProperty('overflow', 'hidden')
        } else {
          document.body.style.removeProperty('overflow')
        }

          },
       {immediate:true}
   );
```

Comment: Just to add something: It is recommended to use `toRefs`. Use it like this: `const { isOpen } = toRefs(props);`

Comment: I found `{immediate:true}` is required to make `watch(()=>props.foo)` to work.